# Introductory book about autoregressive processes

Tags: references, stochastic-processes

What is a good introductory book about autoregressive processes? Ideally, it would cover most of the recent developments in the field. I am looking for this reference both for personal enlightenment and to use as a reference in my dissertation in a related material section.

Wikipedia mostly points to economics / econometrics references, and I am more interested in the statistical point of view.

Comment: In general, it is difficult to cover recent developments in an introductory fashion, as recent developments tend to add additional complexity to earlier ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of them is ***Time Series Analysis: Forecasting and Control, 5th Edition*** by George Box and Gwilym Jenkins. It is one of the most classical textbooks on time series analysis, of course including AR process.